# How can I capture the IP used by cURL in Guzzle?

Tags: php, curl, guzzle, goutte

I'm using Goutte (which internally uses Guzzle) for a web scraping project. I'm working on a custom rate limiter, and so am storing all HTTP operations to a database table against an IP so I can check if a call has been made to a host in a recent timeframe.

Currently I'm using `gethostbyname` to convert the known hostname to an IP address, but Guzzle would already have done a lookup, and so this may be wasteful. Moreover, hostnames may resolve to more than one IP address (hence the need for `gethostbynamel`) so the IP I derive myself may not in fact be the one that Guzzle has used (though, at a guess, there could be some caching at the PHP level that would make it likely `gethostbyname` returns the correct result).

I've subscribed a plugin to Guzzle, which returns some very interesting data from cURL, in an effort to do this. Sadly, the IP address was not among them. There *must* be a way to get this though - any ideas?

```
class HttpLoggerPlugin implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'request.complete' => 'onRequestComplete',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Handles the request complete event (for both success/failed)
     * 
     * @param \Guzzle\Common\Event $event
     */
    public function onRequestComplete(Event $event)
    {
        $request = $event['request'];
        $host = $request->getHost();

        $ip = gethostbyname($host);
        $response = $event['response'];
        $responseCode = $response ? $response->getStatusCode() : null;
        // Try to get cURL data here
        echo $response ? print_r($response->getInfo(), true) : null;
    }
}
```

This is what the `$response->getInfo()` returns:

```
 Array(
        [url] => http://example.com/page.html
        [content_type] => text/html
        [http_code] => 200
        [header_size] => 228
        [request_size] => 149
        [filetime] => -1
        [ssl_verify_result] => 0
        [redirect_count] => 0
        [total_time] => 1.209516
        [namelookup_time] => 0.559758
        [connect_time] => 0.954811
        [pretransfer_time] => 0.954916
        [size_upload] => 0
        [size_download] => 22390
        [speed_download] => 18511
        [speed_upload] => 0
        [download_content_length] => 22390
        [upload_content_length] => 0
        [starttransfer_time] => 1.056913
        [redirect_time] => 0
        [certinfo] => Array()
        [redirect_url] => 
 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_PRIMARY_IP)` or look in the `"primary_ip"` key/value of `curl_getinfo($ch)`.

What's your PHP version? You must be using an old version.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it was [still an issue in 5.4.6](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62912), maybe it got added in 5.5? Thanks also for updating the documentation - just saw that on my old bug report.

Comment: Further to my comment above, I notice this is [now documented](https://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php). The feature was introduced in 5.4.7.